# Unable to get the value of the Commandbutton by Clicking on it at apexclass

Tags: salesforce, apex

VF code:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!strings}" var="stringer" id="theRepeat">

<apex:CommandButton value="{!stringer}" id="theValue"style="padding:10px;spacing:10px"  action="{!repeatFunction}">
<apex:param name="paramValue" value="{!stringer}"/>
</apex:commandButton>
</apex:repeat>
```

Apex Class Code:

```
public String[]  getStrings() {
     return new String[]{'ONE','TWO','THREE'};

}
public String ButtonNum {get;set;}
public void repeatFunction() {
    ButtonNum = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('stringer');
    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.Info,'num'+ButtonNum ));

}
```

Hi Everyone,
I want to display the value of the button by using repeat function. Above is my code and i'm unable to display the button values respectively.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Name attribute value` in the controller

```
 ButtonNum = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('paramValue');
```

`OR`

You can use `assignTo` attribute of apex:param it gives value in controller:

```
<apex:page controller="test">
  <apex:outputPanel id="msg">
      <apex:messages />
  </apex:outputPanel>
  <apex:form >
     <apex:repeat value="{!strings}" var="stringer">
        <apex:commandButton value="{!stringer}" id="theValue"  action="{!repeatFunction}" reRender="msg">
          <apex:param name="paramValue" value="{!stringer}" assignTo="{!ButtonNum}"/>
       </apex:commandButton>   
      </apex:repeat>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Apex Class :

```
public class test
{
  public String[]  getStrings() 
  {
      return new String[]{'ONE','TWO','THREE'};
  }
  public String ButtonNum {get;set;}
  public void repeatFunction()
  {  
     ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.Info,'num :'+ButtonNum ));    
 }
}
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: Happy Salesforce Coding..:)